# Recommendation algorithm applicable in eCommerce site and solved using neo4j graph database

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, recommendation-engine

I am planning to implement product recommendation in my eCommerce site using neo4j graph database .

Recommendation will be based on User action on a product. Actions will be

```
   - Product View , 
   - Rating ,
   - Read book
   - Download book , 
   - Purchase , 
   - Add to card , 
   - Review , 
   - Share
   - Some more action applicable to our site.
```

The graph structure will be

User (Node )

- ID
- Timestamp

Product ( Node )

- Name
- Timestamp

Action ( Relationship between User and Product node )

- Weight ( Given based on the action , eg : purchase : 10 , view : 1 etc)
- Timestamp (Time at which action occurred )

Later I will add social relationship between the User nodes .

I found different recommendation methods and algorithms from my initial analysis from internet .
Following are the list which is categorized based on my understanding . Some of term might be incorrect or redundant or wrong categorization ( Correct me if I am wrong ).

```
 - Item-Item similarity   
       - k-nearest neighbors (k-NN) algorithm
       - Pearson correlation coefficient.   
 -  User-User similarity   
 -  Matrix Factorization    
       - Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)
       - Restricted Boltzmann Machines (RBM)
       - Non-Negative Matrix Factorization ( NNMF )
 -  Latent factor analysis   
 -  Co-visitation analysis   
 -  Latent topic analysis   
 -  Cluster model   
 -  Association rule    
       - Bi-gram matrix association rule
 -  Ensembles
```

My problem is to identify  which all methods are applicable in my eCommerce site  and can be solved using neo4j graph database ( Based on the above model ).

Comment: did you get any helpful link to start up?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about data science rather than how to implement something. Then I point you to the [Data Science StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

If you want to implement your recommendation engine for eCommerce I highly recommend to use [GraphAware Reco](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-reco). Which is Framework for creating Recommendation Engines top of Neo4j.

Here is the scaffold for basic Recommendation Engine based on GraphAware Reco - https://github.com/graphaware/recommendations-meetup

If your application is based on PHP you can use [GraphAware reco4php](https://github.com/graphaware/reco4php)